# Deligne’s tensor product of algebra module categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

$A$ and $B$ are finite dimensional $\mathbb{k}$-algebras. $\textrm{Mod}_A$ is the category of finite dimensional $A$-modules.

In Proposition 1.46.2. of the [note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-769-topics-in-lie-theory-tensor-categories-spring-2009/ae5ba8bcc60b9c523f2bed125d634431_MIT18_769S09_lec09.pdf)，it is claimed that $\textrm{Mod}_{A\otimes B}$ is the Deligne’s tensor product of $\textrm{Mod}_A$ and $\textrm{Mod}_B$.

For any abelian category $C$ and functor $F:\textrm{Mod}_A\times \textrm{Mod}_B\to C$ which is right exact on both variables, how to construct a right exact functor $\tilde{F}: \textrm{Mod}_{A\otimes B}\to C$?

It’s quite obvious for algebraic closed $\mathbb{k}$ and semisimple $A$ and $B$, because every simple $A\otimes B$-module is a tensor product of simple $A$-module and simple $B$-module. But for a general field and algebra, we can only decompose a finite dimensional module into a direct sum of indecomposable modules. Is there a similar relation for indecomposable modules?

Comment: Is your problem defining $\tilde F$ or showing that it is right exact?

Comment: Have you looked at any other source on Deligne's tensor product? This example is basic, it is explained in various places.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira My problem is how to define $\tilde{F}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I tried to find other source, but they all refer to Deligne’s Catégories tannakiennes and I can’t read French.

Comment: https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think this paper is not the one they quoted. They quoted https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/60_categoriestanna.pdf  having a section which seems to be tensor product of abelian category.

Comment: Ahh…I should use the $\otimes$-representation of right exact functor and embed $C$ into another module category. I’m totally in the wrong way when I asked the question because the example I know about is the semisimple category.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for answering my question by myself, but I think it's harmless to record an answer here.

We should embed $C$ to $\textrm{Mod}_R$ for some algebra R.

Note that $F(A\otimes B)$ is an $R-A\otimes B$ bimodule. The $A\otimes B$ structure is defined by $a\otimes b\mapsto F(-\cdot a,-\cdot b)$. The $A\otimes B$ structure is well defined, since $F$ is bilinear on the morphism. Two module structures are compatible, since $F(-\cdot a,-\cdot b)$ is an $R$-map.

We define $\tilde{F}=F(A\otimes B)\otimes_{A\otimes B}(-)$.

To prove the natural isomorphism $\tilde{F}\circ \boxtimes\cong F$, we can choose free resolutions $M_{\ast}$ and $N_{\ast}$ for $A$-module $M$ and $B$-module $N$ repectively. Note that there is an exact sequence
$$F(M_0,N_1)\oplus F(M_1,N_0)\to F(M_0,N_0)\to F(M,N)\to 0$$
the exactness comes from direct computation or using a simple argument of sepectral sequence. The exact sequence is isomorphic to another sequence
$$F(A,B)\otimes_{A\otimes B}(M_0\otimes N_1\oplus M_1\otimes N_0)\to F(A,B)\otimes_{A\otimes B}(M_0\otimes N_0)\to F(A,B)\otimes_{A\otimes B}(M\otimes N)\to 0$$
since $M_\ast$ and $N_\ast$ are free, $F$ is bilinear and $F(A,B)\otimes_{A\otimes B}(-)$ is right exact. Using comparison lemma and universal property of cokernel, we can prove the naturality.

Finally, we need to prove the image of $\tilde{F}$ lies in $C$. We choose a free resolution $K_\ast$ of an $A\otimes B$-module $K$, then $\tilde{F}(K_1)\to\tilde{F}(K_0)\to \tilde{F}(K)$ is exact. Since $\tilde{F}(K_1)$ and $\tilde{F}(K_0)$ are in $C$ and abelian category $C$ is closed under cokernel, $\tilde{F}(K)$ must in $C$.